# Azure October 2012 SDK broke UseDevelopmentStorage=true

Tags: c#, azure

Has anyone tried the October 2012 Azure sdk with usedevelopmentstorage=true connection string ?

```
CloudStorageAccount.Parse("UseDevelopmentStorage=true")
```

throws a 'The given key was not present in the dictionary' exception.

```
CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount
```

works ok.

Is this a bug in the azure sdk ?

Comment: Is the october SDK the 1.7 one? If so I don't get this error.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a bug in v2.0.0.0 of the storage SDK (it requires you to use DevelopmentStorageProxyUri in the connection string if you're working with development storage). These are the workarounds:

- Don’t use the emulator
- Run fiddler and pass the `DevelopmentStorageProxyUri` setting: `CloudStorageAccount.Parse("UseDevelopmentStorage=true;DevelopmentStorageProxyUri=http://ipv4.fiddler");`
- Reference the storage account directly: `CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;`

Comment: What a load of crap. I'm getting sick of this "upgrade" to SCL v2. So far it's claimed 4hrs of my life. This is the icing on the (poisoned) cake

Comment: This error occurs for me in v2.0.3.0. The second workaround suggestion works fine.

Answer (score 12):

This issue has been resolved in a recent release (version 2.0.1) available via [GitHub](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net) and [NuGet](https://nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/2.0.1.0).

We apologize for any inconvenience this may have caused.

Answer (score 9):

Use:

```
UseDevelopmentStorage=true;DevelopmentStorageProxyUri=http://127.0.0.1
```

Which is a shorthand for:

```
BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me (and was the simplest way of fixing the problem).

Comment: When I use that connection string with the 2.2 SDK, I get a 400 error (Bad Request).  (I was getting a 403 (Forbidden) when using a connection string consisting of the Endpoint and Developer storage Key).  Does anyone know if this connection string is supposed to work with SDK 2.2?

Comment: Using DevelopmentStorageProxyUri=http://ipv4.fiddler, fiddler shows that Storage emulator is returning Bad Request "The value of one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format".  The headers are "User-Agent: WA-Storage/3.0.1..." and  "Authorization: SharedKey devstoreaccount1:<base64 string that changes with each request>" The host is 127.0.0.1:10000, and request is "HEAD /devstoreaccount1/images?restype=container&timeout=90" (I'm making a request to CreateIfNotExists() for a container named images.

Comment: You do not use the v2 version, you use the v3 version of Azure Storage. This version is not compatible with the emulator. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/0fb01e56-8a52-4e98-a8bf-dd517d86d879/windows-azure-storage-developmentstorageaccount-cloudtablecreateifnotexists-always-get-400-http?forum=windowsazuredevelopment . This explains why you get a 400 error. Downgrade to the latest v2.1 version: https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage

Answer (score 2):

For those running into problems with the latests SKD + Nuget packages. If you are using the v3 version of the nugget package (WindowsAzure.Storage) you will get a 400 bad request exception. This version is not compatible with the emulator. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/0fb01e56-8a52-4e98-a8bf-dd517d86d879/windows-azure-storage-developmentstorageaccount-cloudtablecreateifnotexists-always-get-400-http?forum=windowsazuredevelopment .

Downgrade to the latest v2.1 version: https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage and you are good to go. Open the package manager console and do the following:

```
uninstall-package WindowsAzure.Storage    
install-package WindowsAzure.Storage -version 2.1.0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

@Stevoman,

This does work, thanks! (And no need to fire fiddler)

But seems still able to break some code, as the endpoint is 
    `http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1` 
while a normal parse from a real string will get 
    `https://something.blob.core.windows.net/`
Note the last slash. If one is combining several pieces for a URI then need to careful.